# How can I delete whitespace from middle of string but keep whitespace at beginning?

Tags: regex, apache, regexp-replace

Sometime years ago ALL of our Apache config files changed to have whitespace all over the place (see below, no idea who did it). Since I am upgrading from 2.2 to 2.4 this makes it tricky to find and replace all the required config changes.

I thought to get rid of the whitespace in the middle but keep the whitesapce at the front. I know how to replace at the beginning, end and everywhere. I even consulted a few books (e.g. Jeff Friedl's regexp) but I cannot get my head around this - not even sure whether this is possible.

```
  <Directory            "THEDIRECTORY">
    <LimitExcept        GET POST>
      deny              from all
    </LimitExcept>
    Options             -Indexes -MultiViews
    AllowOverride       All
    Order               allow,deny
    Allow               from all
  </Directory>
```

What I would like is this:

```
  <Directory "THEDIRECTORY">
    <LimitExcept GET POST>
      deny from all
    </LimitExcept>
    Options -Indexes -MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
```

So I can easily search for and replace the config changes for apache 2.4

I thought coming from the end

```
s/\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+$/$1$2/g
```

but this does not work for a number of reasons including that the number of replacements change, they are a non fixed number.

Help please, I am clueless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to match any horizontal whitespace two or more at a time and replace it with a single space.

```
(?<=\S)\h{2,}(?=\S)
```

This regex ensures, only space will be matched that is surrounded by some non-space character using `\S`

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/y4uY2U/1)**

In case `\h` is not supported in your regex, you can use just a space instead of `\h` and write your regex as,

```
(?<=\S) {2,}(?=\S)
```

**[Demo using space only](https://regex101.com/r/y4uY2U/2/)**

Comment: Full explanation about the look-ahead and look-behind found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your add the following line to your .htaccess or apache conf file dire tory tag if it’s not already there:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Then below add

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \s
>
> RewriteRule .* https://DOMAIN_NAME/ [R=301,L]

Replacing DOMAIN_NAME.